# Cut and replace bash

Tags: bash, shell, cut

I have to process a file with data organized like this

```
AAAAA:BB:CCC:EEEE:DDDD
FF:III:JJJ:KK:LLL
MMMM:NN:OOO:PP
etc
```

Columns can have different length but lines always have the same number of columns.

I want to be able to cut a specific column of a given line and change it to the value I want.

For example I'd apply my command and change the file to

```
AAAAA:BB:XXXX:EEEE:DDDD
FF:III:JJJ:KK:LLL
MMMM:NN:OOO:PP
```

I know how to select a specific line with sed and then cut the field but I have no idea on how to replace the field with the value I have.

Thanks

Comment: Consider using [sed](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sed) or [awk](http://wikipedia.org/wiki/Awk)

Comment: A simple `sed s/val/rep/` should do it.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Here's a way to do it with `awk`:

Going with your example, if you wanted to replace the 3rd field of the 1st line:

```
awk 'BEGIN{FS=OFS=":"} {if (NR==1) {$3 = "XXXX"}; print}' input_file
```

**Input:**

```
AAAAA:BB:CCC:EEEE:DDDD
FF:III:JJJ:KK:LLL
MMMM:NN:OOO:PP
```

**Output:**

```
AAAAA:BB:XXXX:EEEE:DDDD
FF:III:JJJ:KK:LLL
MMMM:NN:OOO:PP
```

**Explanation:**

- `awk`: invoke the awk command
- `'...'`: everything enclosed by single-quotes are instructions to awk
- `BEGIN{FS=OFS=":"}`: Use `:` as delimiters for both input and output. `FS` stands for Field Separator. `OFS` stands for Output Field Separator.
- `if (NR==1) {$3 = "XXXX"};`: If Number of Records (`NR`) read so far is 1, then set the 3rd field (`$3`) to "`XXXX`".
- `print`: print the current line
- `input_file`: name of your input file.

---

If instead what you are trying to accomplish is simply replace all occurrences of `CCC` with `XXXX` in your file, simply do:

```
sed -i 's/CCC/XXXX/g` input_file
```

Note that this will also replace partial matches, such as `ABCCCDD` -> `ABXXXXDD`

Comment: There's just one thing, if I use this commande it outputs the modified version with the original version in the file looking like this :

Comment: AAAAA:BB:XXXX:EEEE:DDDD
FF:III:JJJ:KK:LLL
MMMM:NN:OOO:PP
AAAAA:BB:CCC:EEEE:DDDD
FF:III:JJJ:KK:LLL
MMMM:NN:OOO:PP

Comment: Can you edit your original question to include the actual exact command that you run and the output? comments discard formatting.

Comment: This solution is more idiomatically written:`awk 'NR==1{$3="XXXX"}1'  FS=: OFS=: input_file`

Comment: @WilliamPursell Would you mind explaining what the 2nd `1` does in `'NR==1{$3="XXXX"}1'`?

Comment: @sampson-chen The `1` causes each line to be printed.  It is a synonym for the unconditional action block `{print}`.

Comment: @WilliamPursell thanks! =) is that the only syntactical sugar, or is there a source you can point me to for more reading on this specifically?

Comment: `man awk`, http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/utilities/awk.html, and http://shop.oreilly.com/product/9781565922259.do

Answer (score 1):

This might work for you (GNU sed):

```
sed -r 's/^(([^:]*:?){2})CCC/\1XXXX/' file
```

or

```
awk -F: -vOFS=: '$3=="CCC"{$3="XXXX"};1' file
```